# angular ui-sref on tr - link not visible

Tags: html, angularjs, hover, ui-sref

I placed ui-sref attribute in tr element.

```
<tr ui-sref="test" ng-repeat="d in data">
```

Everything runs well, but I would like the link to 'test' to be visible in the bottom of the browser when hover the row of the table. Is there a way to obtain it?

Comment: That sounds like a job for CSS. Can you please update your question to show the table (including the *problematic* link) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you mean as link in browser status bar?

Comment: Yes, I meant link in browser status bar

Comment: You need to use an `<a>` tag for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function(){
    this.model = {};
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">

<span ng-mouseover="myCtrl.model.mouseIsOver = true"
     ng-mouseout="myCtrl.model.mouseIsOver = false">
     Hover me
</span>

<div ng-if="myCtrl.model.mouseIsOver">
test
</div>

</div>
```

Not really related to ui-router but you can do this with built in directives in the ng main module.